# Dropdown does not disappear when focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a drop down menu that would display sub-menus on a click using CSS pseudo class called focus-within, but it does not work if I click the dropdown menu (Click to dropdown) again.

I have added the code in the code snippet, so you can run the example.

```css
.example-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid 2px #000000;

}

.example-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.example-dropdown > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
}

.example-dropdown:focus-within > ul {
    display: flex;
}

.example-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.example-dropdown > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #000000;
}

.example-dropdown > a::after {
    content: " \2193"
}
```

```html
 <ul class="example-menu">
    <li class="example-dropdown">
        <a tabindex="0">Click to dropdown</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li class="example-dropdown">
                <a tabindex="0">Click to dropdown</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The dropdown does not disappear.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: You need to use javascript for that to work. Try looking at toggle

Comment: You can't do it with only focus within. You better off using js. Or if you really want to do it with css. You probably will need the checkbox trick to make menu disappear on a second click.

Comment: Just take a look at any framework (like Bootstrap) and see how it is done.

Comment: I can use toggle using jquery, but the dropdown menu is based on focus. So it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement JavaScript to achieve the **toggle** feature.

This is the code for the JS part that'll achieve what you're looking for:

```
// Parent Dropdown Menu
let menu1 = document.getElementById('parentMenu');
let list1 = document.getElementById('parentList');

// Child Dropdown Menu
let menu2 = document.getElementById('childMenu');
let list2 = document.getElementById('childList');

// Toggle Effect
menu1.onclick = function() {
    if (list1.style.display === 'block') {
        list1.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        list1.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

menu2.onclick = function() {
    if (list2.style.display === 'block') {
        list2.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        list2.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

The only change you need to do to your code is to add **IDs** for the parts you want to take this effect.

***I added the effect to both of your dropdowns(Parent and Child).***

**Parent:**

```
...
<a tabindex="0" id="parentMenu">Click to dropdown</a>
<ul id="parentList">
...
```

**Child:**

```
...
<a tabindex="0" id="childMenu">Click to dropdown</a>
<ul id="childList">
...
```

```js
// Parent Dropdown Menu
let menu1 = document.getElementById('parentMenu');
let list1 = document.getElementById('parentList');

// Child Dropdown Menu
let menu2 = document.getElementById('childMenu');
let list2 = document.getElementById('childList');

// Toggle Effect
menu1.onclick = function() {
    if (list1.style.display === 'block') {
        list1.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        list1.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

menu2.onclick = function() {
    if (list2.style.display === 'block') {
        list2.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        list2.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
.example-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid 2px #000000;

}

.example-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.example-dropdown > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
}

.example-dropdown:focus-within > ul {
    display: flex;
}

.example-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.example-dropdown > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #000000;
}

.example-dropdown > a::after {
    content: " \2193"
}
```

```html
 <ul class="example-menu">
    <li class="example-dropdown">
        <a tabindex="0" id="parentMenu">Click to dropdown</a>
        <ul id="parentList">
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li class="example-dropdown">
                <a tabindex="0" id="childMenu">Click to dropdown</a>
                <ul id="childList">
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this was what you were looking for as your question was a bit unclear regarding where exactly you wanted the toggle effect.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I guess I mean that when you press "Click to dropdown" it should disappear. Not what's inside, I'm not interested in that. Only the ability to close the dropdown menu when you click on it like on / off.

Comment: @stigmadev Both dropdown menus or just the parent one? The code I provided targets the second "Click to dropdown". Which one do you want?

Comment: not the second "Click to dropdown"  but the first one. The ability to close the dropdown menu when you click on it

Comment: @stigmadev Got it. I'll edit the answer right now.

Comment: @stigmadev Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but the focus is gone. It should be possible to close the dropdown menu if you click outside as in my first example.

Comment: @stigmadev This article might help you: https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-close-a-dropdown-on-click-outside

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JavaScript you can try something like down below.

First you should add a checkbox element to your html.

```
<ul class="example-menu">
    <li class="example-dropdown">
        <a tabindex="0">Click to dropdown</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="click_effect" name="" id="index-0">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
            <li class="example-dropdown">
                <a tabindex="0">Click to dropdown</a>
                <input type="checkbox" class="click_effect" name="" id="index-1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you sould add some new properties in css file.

```
#index-0:checked + ul, #index-1:checked + ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

Now you will need to remove the code below.

```
.example-dropdown:focus-within > ul {
    display: flex;
}
```